# How to install pandoc

Tags: manjaro, haskell, cabal, pandoc

I tried to install pandoc on manjaro and therefore I installed ghc and caball-install, but I got an error by executing "cabal update"

```
$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal: Codec.Compression.Zlib: premature end of compressed stream
```

I also were not able to  install Pandoc with help AUR.

Comment: Sounds more like an in an internet issue more than anything else. Check your connection etc. The issue may also be on the server end, in which case try again in a couple of hours. Failing that, please add the contents of your `.cabal/config` file and also tell use which version of `cabal` you have.

Comment: Doesn't your distribution have a binary package for this?

Comment: @Faheem: the pandoc development is very fast-paced, packages are often outdated.

Comment: Enabling [haskell-core] and installing their binary package for `pandoc` is the most sensible solution.